# Notepad sample has deprecated live folders - security issue - is there an equivalent sample without it?

Tags: android

I wanted to learn and modify the Notepad sample but found it is heavily dependent on live folders which has been deprecated

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/LiveFolders.html

> This class was deprecated in API level 14. Live folders are no longer
>   supported by Android. These have been replaced by the new AppWidget
>   Collection APIs introduced in HONEYCOMB. These provide all of the
>   features of live folders plus many more. The use of live folders is
>   **greatly discouraged** because of **security issues** they introduce -- publishing a live folder requires making all data show for the live
>   folder available to all applications with no permissions protecting
>   it.

Wondering if is there an equivalent sample without it that one can use?

Comment: *...heavily dependent on live folders...* - I don't understand why you would say that. To remove the offending live wallpaper part you just need to ignore/delete one `activity`, a couple of lines of code and some switch cases that are very clear. And no, I don't recall any official notepad sample without that part.

Comment: @Luksprog I don't understand the concept of 'live folders' hence do not know how critical it is to the app.

Answer (score 0):

[LiveFolders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/LiveFolders.html) were used to display any source of data on the Home screen without forcing the user to launch an application. Starting from Honeycomb they have been replaced by [AppWidget Collection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections). So you can safely ignore/remove this functionality in the Notepad tutorial unless you're interested in this specific feature.